# PendingIntent.getBroadcast() not working in Android 11

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-11

**What I want**:
I want to perform a certain action when the user manually removes my App's notification.

**How I implemented it**:
I implemented this by creating a `PendingIntent` that will perform a broadcast using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. I then pass this intent to the `setDeleteIntent()` method of the `Notification.Builder`.

This was working fine on previous Android versions, but in Android 11 the Broadcast is not being sent (or at least it is not received by my receivers). I assume the problem is either with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` (seems more likely to me) or with `setDeleteIntent()`.

**Hint 1:**
I made sure that my BroadcastReceivers are working fine: when I'm performing a broadcast with `sendBroadcast(new Intent(BROADCAST_REMOVE_NOTIFICATION));` it works perfectly fine.

**Hint 2:**
I just noticed that in a state where my App's notification was previously not removable (during playback of an audio file, where I started the player service as a foreground service) it is now removable in Android 11. Not sure if this has something to do with above problem though.

I have no idea what might cause this difference in behavior between Android 11 and previous versions. Can anybody help?

```java
// Set up intent to stop service when notification is removed
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_REMOVE_NOTIFICATION);
PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

// Create a new notification
mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        // Hide the timestamp
        .setShowWhen(false)
        // Set the notification style
        .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                // Attach our MediaSession token
                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                // Show our playback controls in the compat view
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
        // Set the notification color
        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
        // Set the large and small icons
        .setLargeIcon(notificationCover)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_new)
        // Set notification content information
        .setContentText(mActiveAudio.getAlbumTitle())
        .setContentTitle(audioTitle)
        // Set the intent for the activity that is launched on click
        .setContentIntent(launchIntent)
        // Set intent that is launched on delete notificaiton
        .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)
        // Set the visibility for the lock screen
        .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        // Make notification non-removable if the track is currently playing
        .setOngoing(title.equals(getString(R.string.button_pause)))
        // Add playback actions
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_backward, getString(R.string.button_backward), playbackAction(3))
        .addAction(notificationAction, title, play_pauseAction)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_forward, getString(R.string.button_forward), playbackAction(2));
```

Comment: Use an explicit `Intent` (identifiying your receiver class), not an implicit `Intent` (with an action string). Implicit broadcasts have been banned for a few years.

Comment: No matter if explicit or implicit, Notification.deleteIntent doesn't seem to be fired since Android 11 when notification is swiped to left/right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TaskStackBuilder` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` it working all APIs old and new

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
// Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

**Source** : [android developer](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation#java)

Comment: How does TaskStackBuilder send a broadcast?